# Type annotation database for Clojure.Core functions?

Tags: clojure

Does anyone know of a database that lists type annotations for all or some of the functions in Clojure.Core? Ideally, functions should be grouped by type annotation.

Please let me know how I can make this question more clear if my phrasing is ambiguous.

Comment: what do you mean when you say type annotations? in general, people uses clojure + datomic

Comment: Have you looked into [Typed Clojure](http://typedclojure.org/)?